# Search in multidimensional array (Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

**The Question**

Write a function that gets a sequence and value and returns true/false depending on whether the variable exists in a multidimensional sequence.

Example:

```js
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e'); // should return true
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'a'); // should return true
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'f'); // should return false
```

**My Solution Seems To Work, but Code Wars says: "arr.flat is not a function.**

I use the free code camp browser to run and test my code, and my console logs suggested I had it working, but Code Wars was saying arr.flat is not a function. Here is my code:

```js
var locate = function(arr, value){
  let count = 0;
  arr.flat().map((item)=>{
    value == item ? count++ : count;
  });

  return count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

**My Question**

Is my code correct or not? If not, what's wrong. If so, why might Code Wars be throwing an error?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) isn't yet widely supported, maybe Code Wars doesn't support it either? You could still use [one of the alternatives MDN proposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternatives).

Comment: that makes sense! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `.flat` for this (although that would allow the most elegant solution of `const locate = (arr, value) => arr.flat().includes(value);`). Here's a simple recursive solution using an ordinary `for` loop:

```
const locate = function(arr, value) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) {
      if (locate(arr[i], value) {
        return true;
      } 
    }
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working here. So chances are the browser on which you're testing doesn't support `flat()`

```js
var locate = function(arr, value){
  let count = 0;
  arr.flat().map((item)=>{
    value == item ? count++ : count;
  });
  return count > 0 ? true : false;
}

console.log(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e')); // should return true
console.log(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'a')); // should return true
console.log(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'f')); // should return false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach with a short circuit on find.

```js
function locate(array, value) {
    return array.some(v => Array.isArray(v) && locate(v, value) || v === value);
}

console.log(locate(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e']]], 'e')); // true
console.log(locate(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e']]], 'a')); // true
console.log(locate(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['e']]], 'f')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `flat` is supported in your environment, Write own flat method and use the `includes`

```js
const flat = (arr, res = []) => (
  arr.forEach((item) =>
    Array.isArray(item) ? flat(item, res) : res.push(item)
  ),
  res
);

const locate = (arr, value) => flat(arr).includes(value);

console.log(locate(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]], "e"));
console.log(locate(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]], "a"));
console.log(locate(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]], "f"));
```